# I can't check if field exists in document when working on firestore rules

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm working on an app Firestore database that has quiz documents. every document may have a string array field called peopleCanAccess.

What do I want to do in the rules? 
If the document has this field (peopleCanAccess) the only people exist in peopleCanAccess can read the document. and if this field does not exist all authenticated people can access it.

[image]

I tried:

```
 function existingData() {
      return resource.data;
    }

 function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    function getUid() {
      return request.auth.uid;
    }

    function fieldExists(data, field) {
      return !isUndefined(data, field) && !isNull(data, field);
    }

    function isUndefined(data, field) {
      return !data.keys().hasAll([field]);
    }

    function isNull(data, field) {
      return data[field] == null;
    }



 match /quiz/{quizID}{
        allow read : if 
        (isAuthenticated() && existingData().owner == getUid())
        || (isAuthenticated() && !('peopleCanAccess' in existingData().keys()))
        || (isAuthenticated() && getUid() in existingData().peopleCanAccess)
           // !fieldExists(resource.data, 'peopleCanAccess');

        ...

}
```

These rules not working correctly.

example: 
User with id tcsFStMdplOJSyZsluJBLHeOuJs1 can access the quiz mentioned in the above image although he isn't listed in peopleCanAccess field

query:

```
 db.collection("quiz")
                .whereEqualTo("id", quizId)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                        }else {
                            QuizItem quizItem = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).toObject(QuizItem.class);
                            accessedQuiz.postValue(quizItem);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: "These rules not working correctly." Please edit your question to include an example where the rules are not working correctly.

Comment: Your question should include both the actual data you're working with, and the client app code that tries to make use of that data.  Without all of this information, it's hard to tell what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution,

I checked rules in Rules Playground and didn't find any problem with my rules. it works fine the problem is in my client query. 
I found this in documentation:

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security
>   rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. To save you time and
>   resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential
>   result set instead of the actual field values for all of your
>   documents. If a query could potentially return documents that the
>   client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.
>
> Note: You can break read rules into get and list rules. Rules for get
>   apply to requests for single documents, and rules for list apply to
>   queries and requests for collections.

[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)

How did I solved my problem:
1- break read and write rules:

```
 match /quiz/{quizID}{
              allow get : if 
              (isAuthenticated() && getUid() in existingData().peopleCanAccess)
              ||
              (isAuthenticated() && !checkIfExistsInKeys(existingData(), 'peopleCanAccess'))

              allow list : if 
              (isAuthenticated() && getUid() == existingData().owner)

              allow create : if (isAuthenticated() && getUid() == existingData().owner);
              allow update : if (isAuthenticated() && getUid() == existingData().owner);
              allow delete : if (isAuthenticated() && getUid() == existingData().owner);
       }
```

2- change my client query to retrieve one document:

```
db.collection("quiz")
                .document(quizId)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (!documentSnapshot.exists()){

                        }else {
                            QuizItem quizItem = documentSnapshot.toObject(QuizItem.class);
                            accessedQuiz.postValue(quizItem);
                        }
                    }
                });
```